# Yii2 uploaded image doesn't display

Tags: php, image, yii, upload, yii2

So I've set a CRUD to upload a file to the server's root, in a folder called 'uploads'.
Now, the file is properly saved in the particular folder and the database entry appears to be alright - but the images don't display in the CRUD's 'index' and 'view' actions. Any thoughts on this one?

Create:

```
    public function actionCreate()
    {
        $model = new PhotoGalleryCategories();

        if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post())) {

            $model->image = UploadedFile::getInstance($model, 'image');

            if (Yii::$app->ImageUploadComponent->upload($model)) {
                Yii::$app->session->setFlash('success', 'Image uploaded. Category added.');

                return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->id]);
            } else {
                Yii::$app->session->setFlash('error', 'Proccess could not be successfully completed.');

                return $this->render('create', [
                    'model' => $model
                ]);
            }

        } else {
            return $this->render('create', [
                'model' => $model,
            ]);
        }
    }
```

ImageUploadComponent file:

```
<?php 

namespace app\components;

use Yii;
use yii\base\Component;
use yii\base\InvalidConfigException;

class ImageUploadComponent extends Component {

    public function upload($model) {

        if ($model->image) {

            $imageBasePath = dirname(Yii::$app->basePath, 1) . '\uploads\\';
            $imageData = 'img' . $model->image->baseName . '.' . $model->image->extension;

            $time = time();

            $model->image->saveAs($imageBasePath . $time . $imageData);

            $model->image = $imageBasePath . $time . $imageData;

            if ($model->save(false)) {
                return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }

        }

    }

}
```

And the index file for the views:

```
<?php

use yii\helpers\Html;
use yii\grid\GridView;

/* @var $this yii\web\View */
/* @var $searchModel app\modules\admin\models\PhotoGalleryCategoriesSearch */
/* @var $dataProvider yii\data\ActiveDataProvider */

$this->title = 'Photo Gallery Categories';
$this->params['breadcrumbs'][] = $this->title;
?>
<div class="photo-gallery-categories-index">

    <h1><?= Html::encode($this->title) ?></h1>
    <?php // echo $this->render('_search', ['model' => $searchModel]); ?>

    <p>
        <?= Html::a('Create Photo Gallery Categories', ['create'], ['class' => 'btn btn-success']) ?>
    </p>

    <?= GridView::widget([
        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
        'filterModel' => $searchModel,
        'columns' => [
            ['class' => 'yii\grid\SerialColumn'],

            'name',

            'image' => [
                'attribute' => 'image',
                'value' => 'image',
                'format' => ['image', ['class' => 'col-md-6']]
            ],

            ['class' => 'yii\grid\ActionColumn'],
        ],
    ]); ?>
</div>
```

[image]

Edit: In the dev tools, I can see the correct source for the image. What's more, I can access it by copy-pasting the address in the browser. (the first rows are images taken from the internet through their address, they are not saved locally.)

Comment: I had similar problem, but the think is that is some specific of grid view, in documentation is nothing about this, but what you can do is install kartik and use it GridView and DatePicker it will solve a lot of problems in future.

Comment: Upload picture in folder?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this anomaly: while inspecting the image sources, I found out that Yii prepended the baseUrl to the image source, even though it displayed only the correct bit. So I manually assigned the path that goes into the database - this way the images show properly.

This is the upload function after the changes. To test it for the whole backend, I made it a component, and it works flawlessly.

```
    public function upload($model) {

        /**
        * If the $model->image field is not empty, proceed to uploading.
        */
        if ($model->image) {

            /**
            * Assign current time.
            */
            $time = time();

            /**
            * Create the basePath for the image to be uploaded at @root/uploads.
            * Create the image name.
            * Create the database model.
            */
            $imageBasePath = dirname(Yii::$app->basePath, 1) . '\uploads\\';
            $imageData = 'img' . $model->image->baseName . '.' . $model->image->extension;
            $imageDatabaseEntryPath = '../../../uploads/';

            $modelImageDatabaseEntry = $imageDatabaseEntryPath . $time . $imageData;

            $model->image->saveAs($imageBasePath . $time . $imageData);

            $model->image = $modelImageDatabaseEntry;

            /**
            * If the model can be saved into the database, return true; else return false.
            * Further handling will be done in the controller.
            */
            if ($model->save(false)) {
                return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }

        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

if image upload in folder

you check below code in gridview with own path:

```
[
                'attribute' => 'image',
                'format' => 'html',
                'value' => function($data) {
                    if (empty($data['image'])) {
                        $img = 'default.jpg';
                    } else {
                        $img = $data['image'];
                    }


                    if (file_exists(\Yii::$app->basePath . \Yii::$app->params['path']['product'] . $img)) {
                        if (file_exists(\Yii::$app->basePath . \Yii::$app->params['path']['product'] . "t-" . $img)) {
                            $path = \Yii::$app->params['path']['webproduct'] . "t-" . $img;
                        } else {
                            $path = \Yii::$app->params['path']['webproduct'] . $img;
                        }
                    } else {
                        if (file_exists(\Yii::$app->basePath . \Yii::$app->params['path']['product'] . "t-default.jpg")) {
                            $path = \Yii::$app->params['path']['webproduct'] . "t-default.jpg";
                        } else {
                            $path = \Yii::$app->params['path']['webproduct'] . "default.jpg";
                        }
                    }

                    return Html::img($path, ['width' => '100px', 'height' => '100px']);
                },
                    ],
```

in params.php

\Yii::$app->params['path']['webproduct']:

```
 'product' => '/web/uploads/product/',
        'webproduct' => '/uploads/product/',
```

notice: i use basic template.